# remove underline for material entry control in xamarin forms for android

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, material-design

I need to remove the underline for the material entry control in Xamarin.Forms for Android.

I'm using Xamarin.Forms version 4.8.0.1687, and before that in the previous Xamarin.Forms version 4.6.0.847 I used to hide the material entry underline using the below line. Now, with 4.8.0.1687 - its not working.

```
Control.EditText.Background = null;
Control.EditText.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
```

Comment: Which android version are you targeting ?

Comment: target version 10 and checked with android 9 device.

Comment: @Dev try the answer added below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> remove underline for material entry control in xamarin forms for android

Hi, what is the type of the custom renderer? If you use the **Material** `Entry`, the type should be `MaterialEntryRenderer`.

I tested a basic demo to test the function with the version 4.8.0.1687, it works fine. Here is the related code:

```
[assembly : ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry),typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace TestApplication_1.Droid
{
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : MaterialEntryRenderer
    {
        public CustomEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.EditText.Background = null;
                Control.EditText.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the working gif:
[image]

Comment: Side question how do you record screen as gif? I tried the one included in the emulator but it records a black screen during some pages transition with resolution 1080x1920. and it is faster compared to real.

Comment: I use the licecap tool for screenshot, you could have a try.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [custom renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) with [material visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual/material-visual) to achieve entry underline removal.
For Xamarin Forms Material Visual 4.8+ I am using the below code.

### Xamarin Android

#### Entry

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(EntryMaterialRendererAndroid), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual) })]
namespace XFTest.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class EntryMaterialRendererAndroid : MaterialEntryRenderer
    {
        public EntryMaterialRendererAndroid(Context context) : base(context) { }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.BoxStrokeWidth = 0;
                Control.BoxStrokeWidthFocused = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BorderlessEntryRenderer : MaterialEntryRenderer
{
    public BorderlessEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            ViewCompat.SetBackgroundTintList(Control.EditText,ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent));
        }
    }
}
```